# Lower bound this expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The following expression is a logarithmic expression I am trying to put a lower bound on. Assuming $x,y$ are complex variables.

$$F=\log \left( 1 + \big||x|-y\big|^2\right) $$ where the notation |.| means magnitude of complex number.

Can I lower bound as the following 
$$ F=\log \left( 1 + \big||x|-y\big|^2\right) \geq \log \left( 1 + \big||x|-|y|\big|^2\right)= \log \left( 1 + \big(|x|-|y|\big)^2\right)$$

I am guessing the answer is yes,  since  $y = y \ \text{exp}^{+j \angle y}$ then the above analysis is correct?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The thing in absolute values will always be nonnegative, and the argument to log is a positive real.  Since log is increasing on the positive reals, the log will be minimized when its argument is minimized, i.e., when the squared term is zero (for instance, at $x = y = 0$.). So the min occurs at $\log(1) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, does this mean that the above steps are correct?

Comment: Those steps look mostly OK, yes. The final statement about $y$ seems to be missing absolute values around the $y$ to the right of the $=$ sign.

Answer (score 0):

You always have $||x|-|y|| \le |x-y|$ (use the triangle inequality twice to show this).

Then $||x|-|y|| \le ||x|-y|$, and so $(|x|-|y|)^2 = ||x|-|y||^2 \le ||x|-y|^2$.

Since $\log$ is increasing, this gives your inequality above.